# Cordova app not showing in the share list IOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I want to show my app in the share list. The app is been developed in cordova. It is working fine in android but not working in IOS.

I have tried it with the following plugin.

https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-openwith

Followed the instruction given in that plugin, It works fine for Android but not working in IOS.

> Cordova version : 8.1.2
>
> Mac OS version : 10.14.5 Mojave
>
> xcode version : 10.2.1

I want my app to be visible in the IOS share list and would be able to share specified file to my app.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out of how to display the app in the share list of IOS.

In my case the In the **Xcode** >  **Deployment Info** the **Deployment Target** was different for both, project target and share extension target.

Make value of both the **Deployment Target** same and your app will be visible in the share list in IOS.

To resolve the **Data content is invalid** error

In the plugin **OpenWithPlugin.m** file on line no 235.

replace

```
if (![data isKindOfClass:NSData.class] || ![text isKindOfClass:NSString.class]) {
        [self debug:@"[checkForFileToShare] Data content is invalid"];
        return;
}
```

with

```
if (![data isKindOfClass:NSData.class]) {
        [self debug:@"[checkForFileToShare] Data content is invalid"];
        return;
}
```

where **![text isKindOfClass:NSString.class]** is throwing **Data content is invalid** error.

and

On line no 258

remove

```
@"text" : text,
```

This will solve the error of **Data content is not valid**

It will be helpful for any one facing this issue.